# C# DataSet serialised as XML inside a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, dataset

I have a plugin that runs on a third party app. When the third party app creates a new file in its application, I created a [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-5.0) in memory. When the third party application saves the file to disk, I serialized the data for my plugin as a JSON string. And the DataSet in that plugin is serialized as XML and that serialized XML string is stored as one of the field in the JSON.

Is this okay to mix XML and JSON in serialization string? XML and JSON are compatible to stay within a same string? Does anybody used this kind of serialization technique?

Edit :
Adding a sample code

```
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class MyPluginData : ISerializable
{
    public int DataInt {get; set;}
    public DataSet DataCache {get;set;}
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Int", DataInt);
        var stream = new StringWriter();
        DataCache.WriteXml(stream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        info.AddValue("DataCache", stream.ToString());
    }
    
    public MyPluginData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        DataInt = info.GetInt32("Int");
        var dataCache = info.GetString("DataCache");
        var stream = new StringReader(dataCache);
        DataCache = new DataSet();
        DataCache.ReadXml(stream, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    }
    
    public MyPluginData(){}
}
                    
public class Program
{
    private MyPluginData _pluginData = new MyPluginData();
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Using NewtoSoft Json library
        //Serialize like this
        var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_pluginData)
        //Dump this serializedString in the file created by the third party app.
        //Deserialized like this
        _pluginData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyPluginData>(serializedString);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Is this okay to mix XML and JSON in serialization string?* - No way to say without more details.  Can the JSON be deserialized successfully by the same serializer?  Is there any data loss round-tripping the `DataSet`?  Is the resulting JSON well-formed (i.e. if you upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ are there any errors)?   Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: *Does anybody used this kind of serialization technique?* - as long as the resulting JSON is well-formed (i.e. the XML embedded in the JSON as a properly escaped string value) then this *may* have the advantage of embedding the data set's schema as well as its contents in the JSON.  Need to see the actual JSON to be sure.

Comment: OK, looks like the code is indeed writing the DataSet with `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema`.  This will write the schema for the DataSet as well as the contents.  Newtonsoft's `DataSetConverter` in contrast writes only the contents.  Maybe this is good, maybe bad, depending upon whether you need to preserve the schema.